# VB.Net object list cleared unexpectedly after error

Tags: vb.net, list, class, object

This may be a fairly fundamental issue with how I have this written but I need some help:
I have an odject defined as a public class with two fields, both strings

```
Public Class mp
    Dim _fg As String
    Dim _scode As String

    Property fg As String
        Get
            Return _fg
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _fg = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Property scode As String
        Get
            Return _scode
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _scode = value
        End Set
    End PropertyEnd Class
```

I then define an array of these:

```
Dim mps As New List(Of mp)()
```

Then in a loop, I start adding to the list after clearing it first:

```
        Dim mpholder As New mp
        cmd.CommandText = 'Query here
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        reader = cmd.ExecuteReader

        mp.Clear()


        Try

            Do While reader.Read()
                    mpholder.fg = ""
                    mpholder.scode = ""

                    mpholder.fg = reader(0)
                    mpholder.scode = reader(1)

                    mps.Add(mpholder)
            Loop

        Catch ex As Exception
            MP_Res.Text = "error"
        End Try
```

If I end up with an error at some stage and get to the catch, the list 'mp' has the same number of entries in it but they are all empty

Comment: If you're trying to clear the list before you start adding to it, it should be mps.Clear(), not mp.Clear().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You keep adding the same item to the list.

Try moving the line

```
Dim mpholder As New mp
```

within the reading/adding loop:

```
Do While reader.Read()
  Dim mpholder As New mp

  mpholder.fg = reader(0)
  mpholder.scode = reader(1)

  mps.Add(mpholder)
Loop
```

Since `mp` is declared as a `class` that means that it's a reference type, i.e. variables of type `mp` are not the objects themselves, but only references to them. So if I do:

```
Dim mp1 As New mp
Dim mp2 = mp1
```

I would not have two `mp` objects, I would have two references to a single `mp` object. And If I change one property of the object, that change will be visible through each of the references.

```
mp1.fg = "Test" 
mp2.fg = "Test2";
Console.WriteLine(mp1.fg) ' "Test2"
```

Comment: Thanks, I thought it was going to be something fundamental like this. When I stepped through the code, mps seemed to be populating with the correct information and when checking in visual studio all the correct data was in place until the exception, is this expected? By the way, the change fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try the above. You just need to create your object into the loop.

```
    cmd.CommandText = 'Query here
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    reader = cmd.ExecuteReader




    Try

        Do While reader.Read()
                Dim mpholder As New mp


                mpholder.fg = reader(0)
                mpholder.scode = reader(1)

                mps.Add(mpholder)
        Loop

    Catch ex As Exception
        MP_Res.Text = "error"
    End Try
```